# Program crashes when using QList of QLabel

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel

I've made a window that opens by pressing a button.
In this window, I've created a QList of 38 QLabels :`QList<QLabel*> Nombres;` And I allocated it like that :

`for(int i = 0; i <= 38; i++)
    {
        Nombres.push_back(new QLabel(QString::number(i)));
    }`

But when I open the window, sometimes the program crashes and sometimes it doesn't. And sometimes, It crashes when I close the window. It's random.

I've tried to use a table instead of using QLabels but there's the same problem

The program crashes with the error : corrupted double-linked list: 0x00000000019499b0 ***

Any solution ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem is likely that the pointers are getting deleted somewhere else.  There is nothing specifically wrong with your code, but it is an example of poor memory allocation management.

Edit: In C++, you must know who owns all pointers. Some functions take ownership, like adding a QLabel pointer to a QDialog. You can't give the same object away twice.  Once you give the label for a number to the dialog, you don't own it.  If you give it away twice (put the same QLabel on any dialog twice in your example), it will be deleted twice, resulting in undefined behavior and crashes.

Comment: Ok but can I fix it ?

Comment: The question in its current form cannot be answered because there is not enough information provided by the user who posted it. At most this is a guess and since there's no way for the rest of us to tell if the answer is correct or not a downvote is appropriate.

Comment: The answer was correct.  There was nothing wrong in the code that was provided except style. I've added a little  more info because the only reason to have done this code is probably to reuse the same label many times.  C++ != Java.

Comment: No, your answer *might* be right. right now it's just speculation. You could actually be close to having a correct answer but close only counts in horse shoes and hand grenades.

Comment: Hmmm.  The question was "what causes the crash".  The answer I gave was "something after the code you provided."  That is as complete and correct as possible given the info provided.  I then went on to speculate on the missing information and give more details based on that.  What would you have done differently?